# Cutting an object with several plans with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

With geometry nodes, I'm trying to cut a cube with several plans instances.

Some cuts doesn't appear and this is worst if i'm trying to cut an extruded text.

Can someone explain me why it doesn't work ?

Is it another way ?

Thanks for all

[image]

[image]

Comment: Boolean won't play nice with instances, try putting a `Realize Instances` right after `Set Position`. You're boolean-ing planes with no thickness though so you still might get a result you didn't intend. If so, try to edit your question with a visual describing the end result you're seeking.

Comment: It works very well ! Thank you Kuboa !